# "..." last argument of a c static function

Tags: c, function, arguments

What the `...` argument means in the declaration `static void info(const char *fmt,...)` ?

It's part of an `C` library I recently started to use. Sorry if it's basic `C` stuff but I never saw that before and google is not so verbose about `...` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means variable arguments, which means the compiler will accept and compile calls to it with any arguments. Usually their types are indicated by values in preceeding arguments.

Comment: *variable arguments* was the key words I was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

It takes a variable number of arguments in your method.  [I found this article explaining the details.](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html)  It gets very complicated very quickly as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

It is variable argument ([Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)). It is just like printf.

```
 int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

For more info, [check this](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Variadic-Functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

If a functions last argument is written as `...` that means that the function takes arbitrarily many arguments (of arbitrary types as far as the compiler concerned - the function may of course require specific types, but the compiler has no way of enforcing those types).

These arguments can then be accessed using the `va_*` set of functions from `stdarg.h`.